# How to sign a PDF using belgian eID on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: adobe-reader, ubuntu-16.04, smartcard

The Belgian government give citizen a EID card, wich hold a certificate.

It also request the citizen to sign PDF to submit forms.

PDF signature is only possible (up to today) in Adobe Reader.

Adobe Reader is not available in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regroup here informations received from various sources.

- Install the belgian eid middleware

I don't remember how i did that, but it worked flawesly and immediately... Please help me on this :-)

- Install Adobe Reader (thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/805399):

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt install adobereader-enu`

!! when you launch it for the first time, it takes a loooonnnngggg time to show up (far more than a minute).

- Make Adobe use the eid:

Install i386 flavor of pkcs library:

`apt-get install libbeidpkcs11.so:i386`

Locate libbeidpkcs11.so (in my install, it is in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbeidpkcs11.so.0):

`dpkg -L libbeidpkcs11-0:i386`

Launch Adobe Reader and go to Documents -> Security Settings -> PKCS# 11 Module. Then Click on "Attach Module" and browse to libbeidpkcs11.so

And voilà (more or less)

Comment: Should it be `precise partner` regardless of your Ubuntu version?
Also, it doesn't find the package `libbeidpkcs11.so:i386`. Autocompletion only gives me `libbeidpkcs11-0` and `libbeidpkcs11-bin`, but there is no option to get the i386 version it seems.

Comment: I do get a version in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbeidpkcs11.so.0` but Adobe Reader says it cannot load this.